# Does Spring-batch acquires connections from datasource for whole job running time?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Does Spring-batch acquires connections from datasource for whole job running time?

In general I have long running steps in Spring-batch job. During execution Springs takes connection from datasource managed by C3P0 and when steps runs too long C3P0 collects this connections by unreturnedConnectionTimeout - which prevents Springs to finish its manipulations with DB.

In order to manage this I am considering to refactor long running tasklet steps to chunk oriented with hope that Spring acquire connection from datasource only for period not longer than step execution or chunk processing time. And if Springs acquires connection for whole job - this refactoring will not help.

Comment: I didn't find much reliable documentation on spring batch for this kind of question ,most probably it takes connection for whole job. Only way it to try and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Batch obtains connections in a number of different points for a number of different reasons so with the information you've provided, I can't clearly answer the exact question you are having.  That being said, if you have long running chunks or tasklets, each of those are executed within the scope of a single transaction and therefore need to be tied to a single connection.

Comment: Yesterday I checked the code of 2.x version and found that batch using SimpleJdbcTemplate for queries, which does not takes connection for long time - just for query/update and transaction is taken from transcation manager specified for the step - so I think this is the only one point.

Comment: Now I am checking will <transaction-attributes propagation="NEVER"/> reject connection acquire if step will not interact with DB.

Comment: A step always will interact with the db if you're using a JDBC based job repository.

Comment: yes, but this interactions will use short living connections

Comment: does spring batch use same connection throughout the job  for updating meta tables?