# Why does Spring Batch use 1 database connection for each thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch, hikaricp

Why does Spring Batch use 1 database connection for each thread?

Stack:

- Java 8
- Spring Boot 1.5
- Spring Batch 3.0.7
- HikariCP 2.7.6

DataSource config:

- batcdb (postgres)
- readdb (oracle)
- writedb (postgres)

Each datasource is using HikariCP with default 10 connections each.

Spring Batch config:
ThreadExecutor-1:

```
core-pool-size: 10
max-pool-size: 10
throttle-limit: 10
```

Job-1 Config / ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:
(pool sizes and throttle limit set via application.yml)

```
@Bean
public Step job1Step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("job1Step")
            .<ReadModel, WriteModel>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .processor(compositeProcessor())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .faultTolerant()
            .taskExecutor(job1TaskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(throttleLimit)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor job1TaskExecutor() {
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
     pool.setCorePoolSize(poolSize);
     pool.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
     pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
     return pool;
 }

@Bean
@StepScope
public Job1ItemReader job1ItemReader() {
    return new Job1ItemReader(readdb, pageSize);
}
```

Abbreviated Code for Job1-ItemReader

```
public class Job1ItemReader extends JdbcPagingItemReader<ReadModel> {
...
}
```

ThreadExecutor-2:

```
core-pool-size: 5
max-pool-size: 5
throttle-limit: 5
```

Job-2 Config / ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:

```
@Bean
public Step job2Step() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("job2Step")
            .<ReadModel2, WriteModel2>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(job2ItemReader())
            .processor(job2CompositeProcessor())
            .writer(job2ItemWriter())
            .faultTolerant()
            .taskExecutor(job2TaskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(throttleLimit)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor job2TaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
    pool.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
    pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
    return pool;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Job2ItemReader job2ItemReader() {
    return new Job2ItemReader(readdb, pageSize);    
}
```

Abbreviated Code for Job2-ItemReader

```
public class Job2ItemReader extends JdbcPagingItemReader<ReadModel2> {
...
}
```

- There are 2 jobs
- Job-1 is long-running (multiple days)
- Job-2 usually completes in a hour or 2, and runs on a schedule every day
- Jobs are in the same 'application', running on the same JVM
- Each Job has its own ThreadPoolTaskExecutor defined

When Job-1 is running, and Job-2 starts, Job-2 is unable to get a connection to the `readdb`.  The following error is thrown by the Batch Reader of Job-2.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-3 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:97)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject(SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.java:158)
... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-3 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326)
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-3 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:666)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:182)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:147)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:123)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
```

(edited to protect the innocent)

Ref:

- [multi-threaded step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html)
- Similar [question/issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342094/does-spring-batch-acquires-connections-from-datasource-for-whole-job-running-tim), except my transaction should be on the `writedb`, where in this case the `HikariPool-3` is the `readdb`.

Comment: Could it be that your code is simply not returning connections back to the pool? You haven't shared any code, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: I rely on Spring Framework to manage the database connections; I don't explicitly open or close any db connections in my code.  I'll try to add a few more details about the framework portions that are managing the db connections.

Comment: can you post how you are defining taskExecutors ?

Answer (score 7):

The reason Spring Batch uses one database connection per thread (it can actually use more in certain situations), is due to transactions.  Spring transactions are tied to a thread.  Just about everything within Spring Batch happens within a transaction.  So when you have a single job with a single thread, you'll use only a couple connections at most.  However, if you have a multithreaded step, expect at least one connection per thread for the transaction handling.

Comment: Thanks @michaelminella. Maybe it is just too complicated to manage another way, but if my Writer is using a different datasource than the Reader, how does Spring Batch know to which datasource to scope the transaction?  Is there any source, docs or blog that covers this subject more that you could recommend?

Comment: The writer is the one that should be tied to the transaction.  It’s up to you to make sure that’s what happens by having that `DataSource` associated with the `TransactionManager` that Spring Batch uses.  If you don’t, you may get results you don’t expect.

Comment: I am not explicitly setting the transaction manager for any of my steps.  Both Jobs use a JpaItemWriter, and the EntityManager was configured with an explicitly defined transactionManager.  I'm still a bit unclear of where this has left me?

Comment: @MichaelMinella - What max connection pool can be created when working with the millions of records and using Partitions?